# Flex AdvancedDataGrid - Remove sort arrow

Tags: apache-flex, header, sorting, advanceddatagrid

Is it possible to completely remove the sort arrows on an AdvancedDataGrid header?

I know that you can kinda do this by using

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortExpertMode="true"/>
```

and I even tried using

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortExpertMode="true">        
<mx:columns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn sortable="false" />
```

This doesnt work because I have an automatic sort whenever one of the group items are opened. So the grid starts of great looking like this

[closed group http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/85fd6c9816.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/85fd6c9816.jpg)

and when we open a group we are greeted by this fiendish triangle in the header

[open group http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3226375b08.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3226375b08.jpg)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just set the `sortItemRenderer` property to `null` and it worked like a charm.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" sortItemRenderer="{null}" />
```

Comment: For me it crashes in method mouseEventToHeaderPart of AdvancedDataGridHeader so it seems that is not working in the current version

Answer (score 1):

Would a [HeaderRenderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridBase.html#headerRenderer) work for you?

I'm not sure, because based on your screenshot the 'arrow' that you reference doesn't look like it is in an actual header.  In which case I would look into using an itemRenderer to see if that addresses it.

Comment: +1 I found the `sortItemRenderer` property in the link that you gave and set that to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

also set mouseChildren="false"

so that it will not give error on public function mouseEventToHeaderPart(event:MouseEvent):String.

Answer (score -1):

Use this- `sortExpertMode="true"` tag.

This wont give error for mouseEventToHeaderPart event. Worked great for me.